# CSS image percentages behaving wildy

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

I hope it's not a conflict in my CSS styles somewhere, but on my page (http://www.marioplanet.com/product.htm) I'm trying to apply a CSS rule to all images with a class of `FancyBox` to shrink them from `25%` of their original size.

Now, I've heard that this may just be applying to the containing table cell, so please tell me if this is the case.

Also, if the above is true, is there anyway I could do this with just plain CSS and HTML and no JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `width:25%;` would result in width to be a quarter of container size, not original element size.

I think, the best option is to decide what size you want and provide them in pixels.

Comment: The only reason I don't do this is because it's going to be ASP powered, so I wanted a solution without having to adjust it for all of the images.

Comment: agreed... having %s ANYWHERE in your layout is always dodgy. If you know the size of the container you should know/work out the size of your image and hard code it.

Comment: @BOSS Sure, but if image returned by ASP can have arbitrary size, it can quite mess up your layout. (Imagine if each SO user could have icon of arbitrary size: it wouldn't look nice, right?) So, usually you have to restrict size anyway.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the width in percentage, this width will be calculated according to the width of the parent element, here, a `<td/>`. So **the result you have is quite expected**.

Now, if you want to size the images to 25%, you have two ways to do that:

- Get the width on server side, divide it by 4 and set it in HTML. It is an easy, but quite bad solution (see further).
- **Resize the image on server side** by scaling it to ¼, then send the resized image.

The second solution is much better, because **there is no reason to make the users wait four times more** to see the images (and to spend the bandwidth and the server performance). By the way, since you will store the scaled images, there will be no overheat for the server for the resize.

Answer (score 0):

A simple width:75%; isn't enough?

.fancybox{
width:75%;
}